# Sharepoint team sites - Sub-site logo link to sub-site homepage

Tags: url, sharepoint, navigation, graphical-logo

Is it possible to set the URL of the sub-site logo to the sub-site homepage?

Example:

> Parent/Root Site: www.example.com
>
> Sub-Site: www.example.com/abc

Currently when click on the sub-sites logo it takes me to the sub-site homepage.

Is it possible to link it to the parent (root) site instead?

I am using Sharepoint 2013.

Comment: do you have access to designer ...? edit Seattle.master and set URL

Comment: @vinayakhegde Do I have to do it for all the sub-sites though? Isn't there a method where I just modify the masterpage once and the other sub-sites kind of 'inherit'?

Comment: if you are using same master page in all sub sites, then its enough to set once in your root site collection